# Setting stack size in cmake with gcc

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, g++

I am building a C++ project on Linux using *gcc 9.2* and *cmake 3.15*, and I need to increase the default stack size. I found many answers before, but **none of them seems to work**

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack,1000000")
message(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID})
message(${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})
```

It gives an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--stack'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
```

I can see the argument is indeed is passed in the cmake output:

```
GNU
-Wl,--stack,1000000
```

And this following flag doesn't seems to exist at all.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STACK_SIZE 1000000)
```

Comment: Did you try passing `-Wl,stack-size=1000000` instead? It looks like [`ld`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) uses `stack-size`.

Comment: @squareskittles Doesn't work.``set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,stack-size=1000000")`` getting ``/usr/bin/ld: cannot find stack-size=1000000: No such file or directory``. Change ``=`` to ``,`` doesn't work either.

Comment: Apologies, I was a bit confused by the documentation initially, looks like you probably need the `-z` flag before using `stack-size`, so perhaps, this will do it: `-Wl,-z stack-size=1000000

Comment: @KamilCuk OP says the project is "*Linux using gcc 9.2*".

Comment: @squareskittles Solved it, but a little bit different. Can you provide a link to the related documentation?

Comment: Yes, the link is in my first comment. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html). It looks like for the list of additional `ld` "keywords", the `-z` flag needs to be prepended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. Thanks for @squareskittles 's comment. 
It should be:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-z,stack-size=1000000")
```